# Result of Catchfile doesn't work inside a tikzpicture environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, catchfile

This is a follow-up to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312311/7195). I am trying to get points to be graphed using data from an external file. The vertical coordinates are countries, and the horizontal ones are years. For this to work I need to supply the `axis` environment with the list of countries as symbolic coordinates, and this is where I have problems.

In the MWE below, in the first tikzpicture I supply the list of countries manually, and everything is fine. In the second tikzpicture, I supply the list as loaded from an external file using `\CatchFileDef` command from the `catchfile` package. This creates an error even though the command `\listcountries` seems to hold the exact same text as the one I was putting manually (namely : AUT,GER,FRA).

Can you explain why `\CatchFileDef` doesn't work in this context?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents,catchfile}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{testcountries.txt}
AUT,GER,FRA
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{CountryYears.csv}
    #########################################################
    country,year
    AUT,1998
    AUT,1999
    AUT,2000
    GER,1999
    GER,2000
    GER,2001
    GER,2002
    FRA,2000
    FRA,2001
    FRA,2002
    FRA,2003
    #########################################################
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableset{columns/country/.style={string type}}
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{CountryYears.csv}\loadeddata

    \CatchFileDef{\listcountries}{testcountries.txt}{}

    This is the list of countries from testcountries.txt:   \listcountries 

    \bigskip

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[symbolic y coords={AUT,GER,FRA
    },ytick=data,
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
        scaled x ticks = false,
        set thousands separator={},
        fixed},]
    \addplot[only marks] table[x=year,y=country] \loadeddata;
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[symbolic y coords={\listcountries
        },ytick=data,
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
        scaled x ticks = false,
        set thousands separator={},
        fixed},]
    \addplot[only marks] table[x=year,y=country] \loadeddata;
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: TikZ styles do not expand their arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument is not expanded; you need to expand it before `\begin{axis}` absorbs the options:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents,catchfile}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{testcountries.txt}
AUT,GER,FRA
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{CountryYears.csv}
    country,year
    AUT,1998
    AUT,1999
    AUT,2000
    GER,1999
    GER,2000
    GER,2001
    GER,2002
    FRA,2000
    FRA,2001
    FRA,2002
    FRA,2003
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableset{columns/country/.style={string type}}
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{CountryYears.csv}\loadeddata

    \CatchFileDef{\listcountries}{testcountries.txt}{}

    This is the list of countries from testcountries.txt:   \listcountries 

    \bigskip

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      symbolic y coords={AUT,GER,FRA},
      ytick=data,
      x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        scaled x ticks = false,
        set thousands separator={},
        fixed
      },
    ]
    \addplot[only marks] table[x=year,y=country] \loadeddata;
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
      \noexpand\begin{axis}[
        symbolic y coords={\unexpanded\expandafter{\listcountries}},
        ytick=data,
        x tick label style={
          /pgf/number format/.cd,%
          scaled x ticks = false,
          set thousands separator={},
          fixed
        },
      ]}\x
    \addplot[only marks] table[x=year,y=country] \loadeddata;
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a specific reason for not including the \addplot and \end{axis} into the edef of \x ?

Comment: @Peutch Because it's not needed and may cause problems.